# Adding Polyfill / fallback for HTML5 date input?

Tags: javascript, html, modernizr, yepnope

How do you provide a generic, ***unobtrusive*** polyfill or fallback mechanism for an HTML input field with `type="Date"`?

Comment: Check this : http://modernizr.com/

Comment: @adeneo - I'm looking for an unobtrusive solution whereby I don't have to go and edit my current input tags.  This should work across all the major desktop browsers as well as popular mobile browsers.  So, in other words, basically just let the site degrade gracefully if the mentioned HTML5 element / attribute is not supported.

Comment: Here's how you'd do that -> http://jsfiddle.net/RsCL6/

Answer (score 0):

There are a [number](https://github.com/jonstipe/date-polyfill) of [polyfills](http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/07/27/creating-cross-browser-html5-forms-now-using-modernizr-webforms2-and-html5widgets-2/) [available](https://github.com/chemerisuk/better-dateinput-polyfill), you just need to add it as a `nope` value in a yepnope statement

```
yepnope({
  test : Modernizr.inputtypes.date,
  nope : ['polyfill.js'']
});
```